# Cannot get RcppZiggurat seed setting to work

Tags: r, rcpp

After loading package `RcppZiggurat`, I would have expected the following two calls to `zrnorm()` to produce the same set of random numbers, but they do not. I'm on Windows R 3.2.1 64-bit with RcppZiggurat 0.1.3. Am I missing something obvious?

```
> zsetseed(1)
> zrnorm(5)
[1]  0.1596387  1.2358659 -1.5563367 -1.1293016 -0.7745854
> zsetseed(1)
> zrnorm(5)
[1]  0.2214619 -0.3811457  1.0551878  0.2344287 -0.1807683
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when you explicitly select the (preferred) generator:

```
R> zsetseedLZLLV(123)
R> zrnormLZLLV(3)
[1] -0.460512  2.456883  0.117593
R> zsetseedLZLLV(123)
R> zrnormLZLLV(3)
[1] -0.460512  2.456883  0.117593
R>
```

Can you file an issue ticket at the GH repo, please? That will remind me to clean this up on the 'unnamed' function where it should work too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Dirk, and I'll file the ticket.